# How to pass parameters to a packaged container action?

Tags: docker, github-actions

Inside the job definition of a GitHub Actions workflow, I use this external action definition:

```yaml
- name: Wait for backend
  uses: nev7n/wait_for_response@v1
  with:
    url: http://localhost:5984/hyperglosae
    responseCode: 401
```

It works fine but it takes 42s to build the corresponding Docker image.

The logs show that when a container is started for this image, it is called with the following parameters: `"http://localhost:5984/hyperglosae" "401" "30000" "200"`.

To speed up the process, I built and published the image corresponding to this action.

Following the [format specification](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsuses), I changed the `uses` part with:

```yaml
uses: docker://benel/wait-for-response:1
```

As expected, pulling the image is far faster (2s) than building it (42s). But when the image is run as a container, it fails with:

```
invalid value "" for flag -code: parse error
```

The logs show that there are no more parameters sent to `docker run` after the image ID.

Since the format specification does not specify how to use `with` when `uses` is set with a Docker image, I have tried different ways to format the parameters mentioned above. But none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. [Pass then through the `with: args:`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepswithargs):

```
- uses: docker://benel/wait-for-response:1
  with:
    args: "a single long string that you've put all the args into"
```

2. Pass them in through environment variables:

```
- uses: docker://benel/wait-for-response:1
  env:
    code: 123
```

3. [Create a custom action that uses this docker image](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-public-docker-registry-container) instead of calling it directly from the workflow:

```
# action.yml
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone and record the time'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  time: # id of output
    description: 'The time we greeted you'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: docker://benel/wait-for-response:1
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}
```

As you can see you can pass the arguments through the `args` section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
In my case, solution #1 worked fine. Solution #2 would need me to contribute to the code of the packaged container (made by a third party). Solution #3 is a clean solution that I will probably adopt if I use this action again.